# editar base de datos msql mediante php mvc

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Quiero que edite información de mi base de datos pero no me reconoce las variables y quiero que me digan en que me equivoco.

Formulario

```
<form action="<?php echo  htmlentities(CONSTANT('URL') . 'moduloControlUsuarios/CtrEditarUsuario'); ?>" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
        <?php 
                    foreach($this->usuariosid as $row2) { 
                        $ite2 = new Usuarios();
                        $item2 = $row2;        

        ?>
             <div class="agregar agregarM">
                <input type="hidden" name="ci" placeholder="Cendula de Identidad" value="<?php echo $item2->ci; ?>"/>
            </div>

            <div class="agregar agregarM">
                <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value="<?php echo $item2->nombre; ?>"/>
            </div>
            <div class="agregar agregarM">
                <input type="text" name="apellido" placeholder="Apellido" value="<?php echo $item2->apellido; ?>" />
            </div>
            
            <div class="agregar agregarM">
                <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" value="<?php echo $item2->password; ?>"/>
            </div>      
            
            <div class="agregar agregarM">
                <select name="rol" id="">
                    <option value="1">Usuario comun</option>
                    <option value="2">Gerente del área de soporte</option>
                    <option value="3">Trabajador encargado del soporte</option>
                    <option value="4">administrador</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            
            <div class="btnbt btnbtM">
                <div>
                    <input class="bo" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Ingresar">
                </div>
                  
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </form>
```

controlador

```
function CtrEditarUsuario() {

        $ci = $_POST['ci'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $rol = $_POST['rol'];

        $respuesta = $this->model->EditarUsuario(['ci' => $ci, 'nombre' => $nombre, 'apellido' => $apellido, 'password' => $password, 'rol' => $rol]);
        
    
    }
```

Model

```
 public function EditarUsuario($datos){    
      
        $consulta = $this->db->connect()->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET nombre='$nombre', apellido = '$apellido', password = '$password', rol = '$rol' WHERE ci = '$ci'");

        $consulta ->execute();
        }
```

el crup me hace todo bien registrar, eliminar, traer información de la db pero para editar me da error en el modelo y me dice variable indefinida.

hago un `var_dung()` con la variable `$datos` que es la información que traigo del controlador y se trae la información.
Espero que me ayuden que soy nuevo en esto :)

El error que da:

> Notice: Undefined variable: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\bavproyecto\model\moduloControlUsuariosModel.php on line 67
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: apellido in C:\xampp\htdocs\bavproyecto\model\moduloControlUsuariosModel.php on line 67
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\bavproyecto\model\moduloControlUsuariosModel.php on line 67
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: rol in C:\xampp\htdocs\bavproyecto\model\moduloControlUsuariosModel.php on line 67
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: ci in C:\xampp\htdocs\bavproyecto\model\moduloControlUsuariosModel.php on line 67

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, incluye el mensaje de error completo y no sólo un resumen. Qué variable te dice que no está definida? Te sale algún otro error? Por favor, ve a [edit] la pregunta y añade esta información, no uses los comentarios que leer el código acá abajo es difícil!

Comment: Listo y no no me da otro error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mira si esto lo soluciona:

```
$consulta = $this->db->connect()->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET nombre='".$datos['nombre'].", apellido = '".$datos['apellido']."', password = '".$datos['password']."', rol = '".$datos['rol']."' WHERE ci = '".$datos['ci']);
```

El problema lo tienes en el concepto. **$datos** de por si no resuelve las variables en **$nombre**, etc... sino que ***las contiene*** porque es un array, y como tal lo debes tratar.

Aún así, queda más elegante y estará mejor protegida la consulta si la realizas así:

```
$consulta = $this->db->connect()->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET nombre = :nombre, apellido = :apellido, password = :password, rol = :rol WHERE ci = :ci");

$consulta ->execute([
    'nombre' => $datos['nombre'],
    'apellido' => $datos['apellido'],
    'password' => $datos['password'],
    'rol' => $datos['rol'],
    'ci' => $datos['ci'],
]);
```

Al realizarla de este último modo, los valores son escapados, lo cual incrementa la protección ante una posible inyección SQL.

Comment: ok amigo me funciono muchas gracias por tu ayuda  :)

Comment: De nada :-)  Prueba tambien el segundo método que he agregado después en la respuesta, a ver si te funciona, así estará mejor protegida la consulta.

Comment: si la que utilice fue la segunda

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro que te haya funcionado.